# Solar Panel Simulation Circuit working, LT-SPICE

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, current, resistance

I am here again with the same circuit but this time with no errors thankfully. circuit is working but i can not understand the working of circuit. I am not getting why in the single cell's schematic , there is voltage source being used after the load resistor? Isn't load there enough? As there is short circuit current there which is cause by direct sun's illumination. Please if anyone can explain the working of cell as well as panel. Also i have the panel that has 7 cells in series and each cell's Isc=538m and maximum voltage of 2.33 Volts. so where should i modify the circuit with these or where should i put these as in panel's schematic there is parameter for Isc=1nA and in cell's schematic there is source current of 5A which is also being sweeped further..
P.S this is not my model ,i followed a youtube video.

[image: solar panel schematic]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deOjv.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/deOjv.png
[image: single solar cell's schematic]
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wozxg.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wozxg.png
[image: symbol created for input output ports]
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8YxJ.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8YxJ.png

Comment: Charging a 12V battery directly from a solar cell would look rather like your second circuit. Perhaps that's what the voltage source is intended to represent?

Comment: maybe. It is also further being used for voltage dependent voltage source in panel's scehmatic

Comment: I just watched the video you hinted at (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2C28OXu4xA), and he explains much of the questions you asked.  Did you watch the video in its entirety, or just copy the schematics?